# AWS Security Groups Rules- add or delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, network-security-groups

I have been asked to automate addition or deletion of rules in AWS Security Groups. Before I perform the action, I need to validate if the requested rules (taken as parameter) exists in the security groups or not, only if the rule exists we need to add or delete the rule.

I am trying to use below which will list all the ingress rules of the Security Group and delete it:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-XX --query SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[]

aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-XX --ip-permissions "`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-XX --query SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[]`"
```

But I need to just validate if the rule exists or not, if it exists I don't have to perform any activity, if it doesn't exists then I need to add the rule to the existing security group.

Comment: That task is getting rather complex for the AWS CLI. Are you willing to use a programming language (eg Python) to retrieve and examine the Security Group rules? Also, is it really a problem if you add an entry again, or delete a non-existent entry? It might give an error, but the goal is still achieved.

Comment: Hi John, Yes it will be a problem if we try to add the security group rules if it already exists and we cannot revoke any security group rules.

Comment: Add rules that already exist will give an error, but that's fine. Removing rules that don't exist will probably give an error too, but that's fine. So, unless you want to have particularly 'clean' code, feel free to add/remove rules without first checking whether they exist. Would that satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yes, that will help me.